# java: how to find a value in which initial value is zero and getting error "/ by zero"

Tags: java, dividebyzeroexception

I need to calculate accuracy in my java game. So far, I tried several methods however, everytime it either doesn't work or gives me an error "/ by zero". The initial value for bullets_shot is zero and the formula for accuracy is enemies_downed % bullets_shot. How can I bypass this error while getting an accurate read for accuracy? I tried doing a loop where it sets bullets_shot to 1 if it is 0 but it wouldn't give an accurate reading. Is there a way in which I can set a value in place for it until it has a value greater than 1 and if so how would I do so? Here are some code snippets.
here is the full code:
https://github.com/ms12r/Galaxy-Monkeys

In the tick method of the enemy class:

```
if(tempObject.getId() == ID.Bullet)
        {
            if(getBounds().intersects(tempObject.getBounds()))
                {
                    hp -= 50;
                    bullets_hit += 1;
                    handler.removeObject(tempObject);
```

and in the mouseinput class

```
for (int i = 0; i < handler.object.size(); i++)
    {
        GameObject tempObject = handler.object.get(i);

        if(tempObject.getId() == ID.Player)
        {
            handler.addObject(new Bullet(tempObject.getX()+16,
                    tempObject.getY()+24, ID.Bullet, handler, x, y, game));
            bullets_shot += 1;

        }
```

in the game class

```
            System.out.println("GAME OVER");
            System.out.println("Level Reached: " + game.level);
            System.out.println("Accuracy: " + ((Enemy.bullets_hit + Gorilla.bullets_hit) % MouseInput.bullets_shot) + "%");
            Game.INSTANCE.stop();           }
```

Comment: why not wrap the method to calculate the percent in an if statement where you skip it if the denominator is 0?

Comment: shouldn't it simply be the number of bullets hit divided by total shots? why are you using % and not /??

Comment: Thats a typo I meant the / symbol thank you but still doesn't work

Comment: If `bullets_shot` is zero, then `enemies_downed` is zero too, right? What is the "accuracy" when no shots have been fired? There is no accuracy. 0%, 100%, or any other number is wrong. So you need an `if` statement to show nothing, or to show some text instead of the number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a simple method called bulletAcuracy() like the following

```
public static double bulletAcuracy(int bulletHits, int totalBulletsFired)
{
    if(totalBulletsFired == 0)
        return 0;

    return bulletHits/((double)totalBulletsFired);
}
```

Then call it in main like so

```
System.out.println("Accuracy: " + bulletAcuracy(Enemy.bullets_hit + Gorilla.bullets_hit, MouseInput.bullets_shot) + "%");
```

Comment: for some reason this gives me it in the wrong format. For instance instead of 100%, I'm getting 1%. Is there a fix for this?

Answer (score 2):

If the error you're getting is `/ by zero`, consider looking at your calculation.

```
System.out.println("Accuracy: " + ((Enemy.bullets_hit + Gorilla.bullets_hit) % MouseInput.bullets_shot) + "%");
```

Quite simply, `MouseInput.bullets_shot` has no check on it to prevent the error from happening.

You can fix it with a simple `if` statement.

The calculation can only happen without a divide by zero error if (in your case) the user shot some bullets. The case in which no shots were fired could be evaluated as 0 accuracy:

```
...

double accuracy;
if (MouseInput.bullets_shot > 0) {
    // your calculation
    accuracy = (Enemy.bullets_hit + Gorilla.bullets_hit) % MouseInput.bullets_shot;
} else {
    accuracy = 0D;
}
System.out.println("Accuracy: " + accuracy);

...
```

One question remains: why modulus (`%`) instead of division (`/`) for a percent calculation?